# CSS: How do I select a specific universal grandchild of a div?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm trying to select a specific and direct child of a specific and direct child of a div(I don't know how else to say that). However, in both cases, the elements could be anything so I need to use the "*" universal symbol to select these elements.

That may have been clear as mud, here is what I have:

```
.some-div>*:nth-child(2)>*:nth-child(1){
  background-color: #d3fba9;
}
.some-div>*:nth-child(2)>*:nth-child(2){
  background-color: #d3ffe9;
}
.some-div>*:nth-child(2)>*:nth-child(3){
  background-color: #d3fac9;
}
```

As you can see I need to select the 1-3rd children of the 2nd child of a div, and apply style to them. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes. `.some-div > :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(1)` as a selector will work just fine. This will select the 1st child of the 2nd child of the original div. The asterisk `*` is not necessary since you have some specifier already in place for that particular element.

Comment: You already have a correct answer to your own question. There is no better answer for this question

Comment: if you need to test a selector, you can build a simple test case on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/3a8NZ/)

Comment: I like my demo better. :( http://jsfiddle.net/TC7jk/ I'm just too slow.  Edit: and with the cleaner selectors http://jsfiddle.net/TC7jk/1/

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I must be running into issues somewhere else as I can't seem to get any styles to apply with the above selector. However, it's good to know that this selector does work.

Comment: @user3594281 Make sure the specificity of the other selectors is not greater than the ones you have here. You can check in the dev tools of your browser (F12) by inspecting the relevant elements and looking down in their styles. If they are being applied properly they will be below the styles currently showing

Comment: @user3594281 You can start by going up the ancestor tree, and start applying styles to `.some-div > :nth-child(2)` and see if it works, and then check if your `.some-div` is named correctly. They are case-sensitive in some browsers. Wouldn't hurt to check if your structure matches the CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I just made a bone-headed mistake. I was using the wrong class selector name on the above so of course it wasn't applying. I'd never made a selector quite like this before so I did wonder if there were limits on the some pseudo-classes. I'm glad I posted this though because it's worth knowing that I didn't need the asterisk. Thank you for your input everyone!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The asterisk `*` is redundant since you have some specifier already in place for that particular element (the child and grandchild of `.some-div`.

- `.some-div > :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(1)` - Selects the 1st child of the 2nd child of `.some-div`.
- `.some-div > :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(2)` - Selects the 2nd child of the 2nd child of `.some-div`.
- `.some-div > :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(3)` - Selects the 3rd child of the 2nd child of `.some-div`.